# Release item in current year

Tags: sql, oracle

I stuck  in one problem.

```
select substr(tarifa,1,2) as tarifa, count(*) as komada
from pol p, uvod u, doppov d
where (datum_dop >='01-mar-2012')  AND (datum_dop<='01-mar-2013')     
and   p.orgjed = u.sorgz  (+)
and   p.polica=d.polica and d.pov_dopl='P'
--and DATUM_PREKIDA is not null
and d.status='F'
and cisti_ao(p.polica)!=0
group by substr(tarifa,1,2)
```

When I run this query I get all item which is released in period `(datum_dop >='01-mar-2012')  AND (datum_dop<='01-mar-2013')`
Now, I want to update this query:

**All policy which is release, but cancel in current year**

```
select substr(tarifa,1,2) as tarifa, count(*) as komada
from pol p, uvod u, doppov d
where (datum_dop >='01-jan-2012')  AND (datum_dop<='01-mar-2012')
and   izdavanje >= trunc(izdavanje, 'yyyy')
and   p.orgjed = u.sorgz  (+)
and   p.polica=d.polica and d.pov_dopl='P'
--and DATUM_PREKIDA is not null
and d.status='F'
and cisti_ao(p.polica)!=0
group by substr(tarifa,1,2)
```

After I run this query I get same result as first one. From `IZDAVANJE` I need to  take current year only and display all item in this period. 
When I use `extract` method it use only specific year. 
For example:

```
extract(year from izdavanje) = 2021
```

But I want to make in `GENERAL case` wheter user input `2019` or `2028`

> P.S. Unfortunately, it's not possible to use `ANSI-JOIN 92` standard for `SQL`
>   within `Oracle Forms` which's my current environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following in your query:

```
sysdate between trunc(izdavanje, 'yyyy') and add_months(trunc(izdavanje, 'yyyy'),12) - 1

-- sysdate will represent current year
-- trunc(izdavanje, 'yyyy') will represent starting day of the year for the date: izdavanje
-- add_months(trunc(izdavanje, 'yyyy'),12) - 1 will represent end day of the year for the date: izdavanje
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Sure, I need to wait a couple of minute to check answer as accept answer :)